# How to Arrange Table in Array to Prototype?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

So, I want to to modify the Array so that it displays its content in table, row by row, a single time. With the code below it displays the code progressively each element appearing more than once.

How to solve this? thx.

```
$(function() {

Array.prototype.ToTable=function(){

tabelul="<center><table border><tr>";

for(a=0; a<this.length;a++){

this[a]=tabelul+="<td> <div class='Expresion'>" + this[a] + "</div></td></tr>"
}


}

vaz=['one', 'two', 'three','four'];


vaz.ToTable();

$('#show').html(vaz)
})

<div id="show"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you meant to do was something along the lines of this:

```
for(a=0; a<this.length;a++){
 tabelul+="<tr><td><div class='Expresion'>" + this[a] + "</div></td></tr>";
}
```

You should build the `tabelul` variable and then return it.

Here is an example of doing that

Here is a **row** demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2zchT/2/

html:

```
<div id="show"></div>
```

js:

```
$(function() {
 Array.prototype.ToTable=function(){
  var tabelul = "<center><table border>";
  for(var a=0; a<this.length;a++){
   tabelul += "<tr><td><div class='Expresion'>" + this[a] + "</div></td></tr>"
  }
  tabelul += "</table></center>";
  return tabelul;
 };
 vaz=['one', 'two', 'three','four'];
 $('#show').html(vaz.ToTable())
})
```

**Edit**

You should seed that data in before you build the table.

```
var Links= new Array(); 
Links[0]='<a href="http://location.com/"><img src="http://photo1.com/"></a>'; 
Links[1]='<a href="http://location.com/"><img src="http://photo2.com/"></a>'; 
Links[2]='<a href="http://location.com/"><img src="http://photo3.com/"></a>'; 
Links[3]='<a href="http://location.com/"><img src="http://photo4.com/"></a>'; 
Links[4]='<a href="http://location.com/"><img src="http://photo5.com/"></a>';

var vaz=['one', 'two', 'three','four'];

for( var i = 0; i < vaz.length; i++ )
{
 vaz[i] = Links[i] + vaz[i];
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2zchT/4/

Comment: thx for you replay. i need the elements of the array to be displayed by row [one beneath another] not by column.

Comment: @ChrisGP - Oh, just a little tweak for that then, see the demo marked as rows.

Comment: now it works. you have also corrected `a` with `this[a]`. thx. another issue. how to attach to each element of the array a link and a photo from another array `var Links= new Array();

Links[0]='<a href="http://location.com/"><img src="http://photo1.com/"></a>';
Links[1]='<a href="http://location.com/"><img src="http://photo2.com/"></a>';
Links[2]='<a href="http://location.com/"><img src="http://photo3.com/"></a>';
Links[3]='<a href="http://location.com/"><img src="http://photo4.com/"></a>';
Links[4]='<a href="http://location.com/"><img src="http://photo5.com/"></a>';`

Comment: it works with one exception. the position of the photos[links] should be in front of the elements of the first array. now they are behind.